# Linear Algebra, how to prove orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let **W** and **W′** be two finite dimensional subspaces of an inner product
space such that dim(**W**) < dim(**W′**). Prove that there is a nonzero vector
**x** in **W′** orthogonal to **W**.

This should be an easy problem but I'm stuck. Here's what I got: find a basis **S** for the intersection of **W** and **W′** and then apply Gram-Schmidt. Then extend it into **S′** a basis for **W′** and Gram-Schmidt again. There should at least be one vector in **S′** but not **S**. Call it **x**. It should be orthogonal to **W**. But I don't know how to show that.

OK. After some example in lower dimensional space, I found out the reason I'm stuck is because my claim is not true. We might have to do this using dimension.

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can reduce the problem to a finite dimensional one by having the ambient space be $Z=W+W'$.

$\dim (W^\perp\cap Z)=\dim Z-\dim W$ and thus \begin{align}\dim (W^\perp\cap W')=&\dim W'+\dim (W^\perp\cap Z)-\dim (W'+(W^\perp\cap Z))\ge \\\ge&\dim W'+\dim (W^\perp\cap Z)-\dim Z=\dim W'-\dim W>0\end{align}

Which proves the claim.

Comment: The problem doesn't say the inner product space is finite dimensional. So I'm not supposed to discuss the dimension of the orthogonal complement.

Comment: But I think we can restrict to the space W + W' and argue the dimension.

Comment: I solved it based on your idea.

Comment: @FluffySkye True, I had missed that. I'll edit accordingly.